# Relationship between determinant and trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace

Prove  that for all matrices $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb C)$

$$ \det(A+B) = \det(A) + \det(B)+\operatorname{Tr}(A)\operatorname{Tr}(B) - \operatorname{Tr}(AB) $$

---

I have verified it by taking $n=2$ that is for $2\times 2$ matrices. Now how to solve it In general way?

Comment: But Tr(AB)=Tr(Identity matrix)=2

Comment: So it will be 1+1+4-2=4

Comment: This problem is taken from Titu Andreescu book

Comment: The exercise in that book only says to verify it for $n=2$. I'm not sure that this holds for higher $n$, and would be very surprised if it did.

Comment: @SUJANDAS Try it with $A=B=I_n$ for $n \gt 2$. See also [Meaning of the identity $\det(A+B)+\text{tr}(AB) = \det(A)+\det(B) + \text{tr}(A)\text{tr}(B)$ (in dimension $2$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267700/meaning-of-the-identity-detab-texttrab-deta-detb-texttra).

Comment: Yeah got it. For n=4 the relation is not true.

Comment: Consider the case where $A$ and $B$ are diagonal matrices, say $A= \text{diag}(a_1,...,a_n)$, $B = \text{diag}(b_1,...,b_n)$. Then $\text{det}(A+B) =\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)$, while the right hand side is $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i + \prod_{i=1}^n b_i + (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j)$. The left-hand side is thus homogeneous of degree $n$, while the right-hand side has terms of degree $n$ and degree $2$, so this can never hold for $n \neq 2$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083410/339790)

Comment: @SUJANDAS If you are satisfied that the relation does not hold true for $n \gt 2$ then you should either post a self-answer to that effect, or otherwise retract the question altogether.

Comment: @SUJANDAS refer to one of my questions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688492/let-a-and-b-are-square-matrices-of-order-2-with-real-elements-such-that-ab-a